# Can you create names for tuple elements inside a closure's parameter list?

Tags: swift, tuples

This is a property that provides a good-enough representation of luma for a color made up of `UInt8`s for `red`, `green`, and `blue`.

```
var luma: UInt8 {
    return UInt8(
        [(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0){
            let (color, eightBitWeight) = $1
            return $0 + Int(color) * eightBitWeight
        } >> 8
    )
}
```

I'd like it to look like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
[(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0){ luma, (color, eightBitWeight) in
    luma + Int(color) * eightBitWeight
} >> 8
```

Can we get any closer, with no more code than the former?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Int(red)*54 + Int(green)*183 + Int(blue)*19`?

Comment: The code isn't then self-documentating regarding what range the weights are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping for

```
[(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0) {
    (luma, let (color, eightBitWeight)) in
    return luma + Int(color) * eightBitWeight
}
```

But I got compiler errors…

Here is as close as I got.

```
[(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0) {
    (luma, item: (color: Int, eightBitWeight: Int)) in
    return luma + Int(item.color) * item.eightBitWeight
}
```

I'm not sure what the type of `red`, `green`, `blue` are, so I made them `Int`.

Comment: Good job. I wonder why the outer parens are needed. "return" is not, however. Also, I said the colors were UInt8s, but I didn't code-highlight the variable names like you did; fixing now.

Answer (score 2):

I think your original solution:

```
let red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3
var luma: UInt8 {
    return UInt8(
        [(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0){
            let (color, eightBitWeight) = $1
            return $0 + Int(color) * eightBitWeight
            } >> 8
    )
}
```

is pretty good as it is minimal and explicit (though I agree that the tuple unpacking syntax could be simpler still), but if you want compactness over explicit typing, then you could just use the default parameter names:

```
let red = 1, green = 2, blue = 3
[(red, 54), (green, 183), (blue, 19)].reduce(0) {
    $0 + Int($1.0) * $1.1
}
```

But that is harder to read.  If it were my code, I would use shorter variable names, and tweak your original form:

```
let r = 1, g = 2, b = 3
return reduce([(r, 54), (g, 183), (b, 19)], 0) { let v = $0, (color, weight) = $1
    return v + color * weight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to tuples, have you considered enumerations?

```
enum RGBColor {
    case Red(UInt32)
    case Green(UInt32)
    case Blue(UInt32)
    func toLumaComponent() -> UInt32 {
        switch self {
        case let .Red(weight):   return weight << 16
        case let .Green(weight): return weight << 8
        case let .Blue(weight):  return weight
        }
    }
}

[RGBColor.Red(54), .Green(183), .Blue(19)].reduce(UInt32(0)) {
    luma, color in
    return luma | color.toLumaComponent()
}
```

Or even a simple function?

```java
func RGBColorToLuma(# red: UInt32, # green: UInt32, # blue: UInt32) -> UInt32 {
    return red << 16 | green << 8 | blue
}

RGBColorToLuma(red: 54, green: 183, blue: 19)
```

Comment: I'm using a private enumeration for the components, e.g. get { return self[.Red] }, for red's getter. The entire color is stored as a UInt32. ChannelBitOffset.Red is 24. Your functions do what my setters and getters do, but they don't actually calculate a [luma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) value.